# Get the "NA" from one column of a dataset

Tags: r

I loaded my data from a .csv file doing this

```
quiz <- read.csv("hw1_data.csv")
```

If i do colnames(quiz) I get the columnnames from my data

```
> colnames(quiz)
[1] "Ozone"   "Solar.R" "Wind"    "Temp"    "Month"   "Day"
```

I now would like to show the NA values from the first column. I know na <- is.na(quiz) gives me all missing values but I only would like to have the missing values from the first column.

Any help on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Try na <-  is.na(quiz[,1])

Comment: Thansk @AaghazHussain for your quick answer. If i now want to calculate a mean over the values of column 1 (without NA values) what would be the easiest to do?

Comment: The easiest way would be to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example as suggested by David Arenburg

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are doing coursera r programming course

Any way

**My Code:**

```
quiz <- read.csv("hw1_data.csv")
na <- is.na(quiz$Ozone)
sum(na)
```

Since you only want the NA value of the first row specify only the first column value to the is.na function

Which will provide a vector of TRUE and FALSE depending upon the value of the first column

sum function is used to count the number of TRUE value